# Filter function in Python not replicating R output?

Tags: python, r

Could somebody please review the following filter in python?

I'm trying to rewrite an R filter and when I subset the variables individually I am getting the correct sum. However, when I try the entire subset it's not producing the correct output.

Python (not outputting correctly):

```
import pandas as pd

data_18 = data_18[(data_18.weight > 0) & (data_18.drugs != 0) & ((data_18.age > 16) & (data_18.age < 59))]
```

R (outputting correctly):

```
data_18 <- filter(data_18, weight > 0 & drugs != 0 & (age > 16 & age < 59))
```

Comment: Are your data_18 object attributes weight, drugs etc. lists? Can you write a sentence about the structure of data_18?

Comment: Hello, the data is in the tidy data structure i.e. a row is a case and a column is a variable. Hope that helps?

Comment: are you using pandas?

Comment: Yes - now edited to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: try not using dot notation data["weight"] instead